# How to redirect all wordpress posts and pages to a new domain.?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

i need a 301 redirect

www.old-domain.com/simple-post/ to go to www.new-domain.com (not new-domain.com/simple-post)

I tried using some .htaccess rules and did nothing,

mod-rewrite is enabled

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are transfering your WordPress website from a domain to another, this is the way to go :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Almost all the time theses lines do the trick :

```
//FIXME: do comment/remove these hack lines. (once the database is updated)
update_option('siteurl', 'http://your.domain.name/the/path' );
update_option('home', 'http://your.domain.name/the/path' );
```

Of course you also need to change every static links inside your posts and/or template files.

Here is a link that could help replacing links in content :

http://lorelle.wordpress.com/2005/12/01/search-and-replace-in-wordpress-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0):

> put this code on header.php
>       pass in "get_the_ID(1)" post(simple-post)id.
>       set redirect url.

```
<?php if (get_the_ID(1)) { ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
         window.location = "http://www.google.com"; 
   </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thank yout. it did the trick.
what if i want to redirect a wordress domain that uses costum post types to a new one that doesnt use costum post types. I mean domain1.com/article/post-name to domain2.com/post-name?